# VSTO Outlook: How to know if the window being opened is the compose window

Tags: outlook, vsto, interop, outlook-addin, office-addins

I have an scenario in which I need to know if the window being opening is the compose window (that opened when you click on New mail). How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the value of the `Inspector.CurrentItem.Sent` property. Make sure `Inspector.CurrentItem` is actually a `MailItem` object first.

Answer (score 1):

One way you can do it is by using a [FormRegion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/how-to-add-a-form-region-to-an-outlook-add-in-project?view=vs-2022), which has a [FormRegionMode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Outlook.FormRegion.FormRegionMode) property.
That property holds a [OlFormRegionMode enumeration value](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.olformregionmode) that is set by Outlook based on whether the window is in reading, compose or preview (in-line reading pane) mode.